# Converting a decimal number from str to float

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following number of type float:

```
1.019e-05
```

To convert it to a decimal number, i did this:

```
print("%.10f" % float(1.019e-05))
```

Which gives the following output: `0.0000101900`

The problem is that `0.0000101900` is of type `str`, but i need to make some calculations with that number. How can i convert `0.0000101900` from string to a number again? if i use `float()`the decimal will be converted again to an exponential. Am i forced to use the exponential number here?

Comment: Why do you care about the internal representaion?

Comment: `0.0000101900` and `1.019e-05` are two representations of the same `float`. There's no "converting" done when going from one to the other, it's just different representations for the same thing.

Comment: There are no native decimals in Python. ``0.3`` is a float just like ``3e-1``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number is a `float` and has the same value no matter how it looks - the scientific notation used is just a way of representing how the data looks in a more concise way. By doing your formatting string, you are formatting the number to *look* a certain way for output, but that creates a string representation of the number rather than "converting it to a decimal number". You can't change the way Python natively represents a `float`, but I'm not understanding why this matters to you because it doesn't change the actual value of the number, just how it looks when printed out

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Basically i had a large array with numbers in exponential form and i had to look for some specific values when printing the array out. Having it in decimal form made it easier for me to read, rather than exponential form

Comment: @San9096 no problem, and that makes sense but yeah the value will be the same no matter how you make it look, but converting it to a more readable format is always reasonable - as long as you know that it can only be made to look more readable as a `str`